# translog and partnerlogs in websphere

Tags: websphere

In the Websphere Application server i can see two folders namely translog and partnerlog. Recently we got a problem in websphere . As a part of resolution we have deleted the files log1 and log2 in those folders and restarted the websphere. Then the problem got resolved. I wanted to know what is the purpose of these files.

Regards,

Sunny.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The App Server uses the tranlogs to keep information about transactions so that it can recover if something goes wrong (when it work with 2 PC transactions).

In a production box, never ever delete these files (as the WAS Server will never be able to recover transactions if you delete these files)

The transactions involves multiple partners. For eg, you might have transactions involving WMQ, DB2, Oracle etc. All these resourcemanagers (WMQ, Db2) are transaction partners that WAS interacts with.

Have a quick read on this for further info.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/fep/topic/com.ibm.websphere.jpafep.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tjta_mgetlog.html?resultof=%22%54%72%61%6e%73%61%63%74%69%6f%6e%22%20%22%74%72%61%6e%73%61%63%74%22%20%22%4c%6f%67%22%20%22%6c%6f%67%22%20

HTH
Manglu

Answer (score 1):

Transaction Log =>in a transactional system if a node goes down during a transaction, the transactional detail are logged and are available for other node in a cluster
The high availability of the transaction service enables any server in a cluster to recover the transactional work for any other server in the same cluster.

refrence=>

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cjta_trans_ha.html